# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ when calculating limit

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Calculate$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^ndx
$$

My attempt - if
$$
f_n(x) = \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n
$$
converged uniformly for all $x \in [0,1]$ then I could swap integral with limes and solve it:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^ndx = 
 \int_0^1 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^ndx =
 \int_0^1 e^x dx = e^x|_{0}^{1} = e - 1
$$

I must then prove that $f_n(x)$ is indeed uniformly convergent. I already know that
$f_n(x) \rightarrow e^x$. If $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly then for each epsilon the following statement must hold
$$
\sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right| < \epsilon
$$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative approach (without uniform convergence): let $t= \frac{x}{n}$ then
$$\begin{align*}\int_0^1 \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^ndx&=
n\int_0^{1/n} (1+t)^ndt\\
&=n\left[\frac{(1+t)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_0^{1/n}
\\&=
\frac{n}{n+1}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}-1\right)\\&\to e-1.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

You can use Dini's theorem.

On a *compact* set $K$, if a sequence of continuous functions $\langle f_n(x) \rangle$

$a)$ is monotone in $n$ for each $x \in K$

$b)$ converges pointwise to a continuous function of $x \in K$

then the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 1):

To show uniform convergence, you can just estimate the error term:

Note that
$$
n\log(1+x/n)=x-\frac1{2n}x^2+\frac1{3n^2}x^3-\dots
$$
is an alternating series with each term smaller in magnitude (since $x\in[0,1]$), so
$$
\lvert x-n\log(1+x/n)\rvert\leq\frac1{2n}x^2
$$

So for all $x\in[0,1]$, we have
\begin{align*}
0&\leq e^x-\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\\
&=e^x-e^{n\log(1+x/n)}\\
&\leq\lvert x-n\log(1+x/n)\rvert\cdot\sup\{e^\xi\mid n\log(1+x/n)\leq\xi\leq x\} &&\text{(MVT)}\\
&\leq \frac{x^2}{2n}e^x\leq\frac{e}{2n}
\end{align*}
So the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 1):

If $t_n(x)=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$, then, expanding $t_n,$

$t_n(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\cdots+\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\times \cdots \times \left(1-\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$

noting that $0\le x\le 1,$ and comparing this with $s_n=\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}$, we have $t_n(x)\le s_n\le \limsup s_n=e$ and so the result follows by the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The uniform convergence follows from two exercises:

1. For $x\in [0,1],$ $n\ln(1+x/n) - x\to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1].$
2. If $f_n\to f$ unifomly on a set $E,$ and $f$ is bounded, then $e^{f_n}\to e^f$ uniformly on $E.$

To prove 1., rewrite the expression as

$$x\left (\frac{\ln(1+x/n)-\ln(1)}{x/n}-1\right )$$

and use the fact that $\ln'(1)=1.$ For the proof of 2., note $|e^{f_n}- e^f| = e^f|e^{f_n-f}-1|.$

Answer (score 0):

On $[0, 1]$,
$$
\left(1 + \frac x n \right)^n \le
e^x \le
e^1 =
e
$$

So that by the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem),

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \left(1 + \frac x n \right)^n\ dx=
\int_0^1 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac x n \right)^n\ dx =
\int_0^1 e^x\ dx =
e - 1
$$